# How do I split out a multi-index dataframe with a column full of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe as follows (It has multiple variables but I am only concerned about turning the dictionary column into a seperate dataframe)

```
| Index    | Attributes     | Day  | Colour|
| -------- | -------------- | ---- |-------|
| Alpha    | {A1: 1, A2: 2} | Mon  |Black  |
| Bravo    | {A1: 3, B1: 4} | Mon  |Red   |
| Charlie  | {C1: 5, A2: 6} | Mon  |Yellow|
```

I only want the two first variables, how do I break it apart so it looks like this

```
| Index    | A1   | A2   | B1 | C1|
| -------- | ---- | ---- |----|----|
| Alpha    |1     |2     |N/A |N/A |
| Bravo    |3     |N/A   |4   |N/A |
| Charlie  |N/A   |6     |N/A |5   |
```

I'm really stumped on this issue and this is the code I attempted:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Index'])
new_df['Index'] = old_df['Index'        
attribute_df = pd.Dataframe(old_df['attributes'])
new_df = pd.concat(new_df, attribute_df)
```

It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column `Index` is actually the index of the frame use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) :

```
new_df = df['Attributes'].apply(pd.Series)
```

```
          A1   A2   B2   C1
Index                      
Alpha    1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
Bravo    3.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
Charlie  NaN  6.0  NaN  5.0
```

Assuming `Index` is a column add a [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) to merge back to the DataFrame (use this option also to save more columns than just the index):

```
new_df = df[['Index']].join(df['Attributes'].apply(pd.Series))
```

```
     Index   A1   A2   B2   C1
0    Alpha  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
1    Bravo  3.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
2  Charlie  NaN  6.0  NaN  5.0
```

---

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie'],
    'Attributes': [{'A1': 1, 'A2': 2}, {'A1': 3, 'B2': 4}, {'C1': 5, 'A2': 6}],
    'Day': ['Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon'],
    'Colour': ['Black', 'Red', 'Yellow']
}).set_index('Index')

new_df = df['Attributes'].apply(pd.Series)
print(new_df)
```